# BizTalk2013r2 Flat File Schema wizard for nested repeating records

Tags: biztalk

I need to create a Flat file schema out of a .csv file having repeated lines:

#Constant

#Date: 1.1.1999

Type1;xxx;yyy;zzz;aaa;bbb

Type2;xxx;yyy;zzz;aaa;bbb

Type3;xxx;yyy;zzz;aaa;bbb

0;123;222;333;444

1;1;22;333;2;22

1;2;33;22;2;22

1;;;33;3;33

2;100;22;1;222;11;22

0;23;22;33;44

1;2;11;22;11;22

1;22;11;22;22;33

0;23;22;55;66

1;22;11;22;66;77

As you can see the rows of type 0,1 and 2 are repeating.

I tried to create flat file considering #Constant till Type3 as field elements and 0,1,2 rows as repeating records with their respective tag identifiers. But since these rows are repeating , i am getting error while validating schema instance.

Comment: Could you share the schema that you are using now? It'll be helpful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the schema using the flat file schema wizard and some manual modification.

Start with the wizard.

First create the schema for the repeating part: select the first block of lines `0,1,1,1,2,` leave the delimiter empty (remove the default value) and set element type to "Repeating record". The default name will be `Root_Child1`.

Parse it into child nodes with `CRLF` as delimiter. Set the element type of line 0, the first line 1 and line 2 to "Repeating record" and set it to "Ignore" for the second and third line 1. You will end up with three child records (`Root_Child1_Child1`, `Root_Child1_Child2` and `Root_Child1_Child5`).

Continue parsing these child records into fields using the semicolon as delimiter and setting tag identifiers to `0, 1 and 2` respectively. Finally, on the record node representing line 2 (`Root_Child1_Child5`) modify Min Occurs to `0`.

Now manually add a sibling record node before `Root_Child1` to represent the constant block. Right click it and select `"Define Record from Flat File Instance"`. Select the top five lines, leave the delimiter empty and set the element type to `Record`. Continue by parsing the record into 5 child records with `CRLF` as delimiter. You can then parse those child records into field nodes with a semicolon delimiter if you wish.

Comment: Hi , I tried your suggestion but its throwing error while validating the instance . The error says : Unrecognized data in the remaining stream. I tried creating sibling record for the constant part before root child1 which comes on the 'root' itself and also tried adding sibling record on root child1 ..in both the cases its throwing the same error.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's missing, maybe some element is not set to be repeating so the parser does not expect more data. I'm sharing my generated [schema file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah9UMfZLxUFKrcYkmLLxeMa4_MrlvQ) that validates with the sample message in your question.

Comment: It worked when i created it the other way around . 1st created the schema for the constant values row that is the top 5 rows. then created a sibling record on the root and with empty delimiter created repeating record and then with delimiter CRLF created repeating records for 0 1 and 2 with the record 2 being of min occurs to 0 . and now its working even if there is no row of tag identifier 2.